# toggle div find child image not working jquery

Tags: jquery

By clicking on the button `.iconToggler` I want to toggle the icon from `.upload` from icon A to Icon B....

It works partially till I add this line `if(!$(".container").find("span").length) $(".container").append("<span>Icon B</span>");` .. that only append Icon B in case not exists previously.

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> [html] 
  <div class="upload">Icon A</div>
</div>


<div class="iconToggler"> toggler Upload Icon </div>
```

JQUERY

```
   $(".iconToggler").on("click",function() { 
      $(".upload").toggle(0, function() {

          $(this).is(":visible") ? $(this).html("Icon A") : if(!$(".container").find("span").length) $(".container").append("<span>Icon B</span>");


 });


 });
```

Comment: You cannot write an `if` into a `ternary operator`. You can add a `ternary operator` into another one though.

Comment: Ok I understood. So this is a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You may use [.html( function )](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function):

```js
$(".iconToggler").on("click", function () {
  $(".upload").html(function (idx, txt) {
      return  (txt == "Icon A") ? "<span>Icon B</span>" : "Icon A";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="upload">Icon A</div>
</div>
<div class="iconToggler"> toggler Upload Icon</div>
```

Comment: this is a good approach. thank you. What if I want to use a function once this `Icon A ` has showed up?

Comment: I meant ...once this Icon A appears instead of Icon B

Comment: you may add **.is(":visible")** test before calling the **html()** function.